# How to Export a mixture distribution to .json file

Tags: export, dataset, json-format

I would like to export the following mixture distribution mathematica found for my dataset to .json file

```
dis = FindDistribution[selection]

MixtureDistribution[
  {0.874492,0.125508},
  {LogisticDistribution[19.2103, 0.155169],
   CauchyDistribution[23.5492, 2.24062]
  }
]
```

I tried to look into the documentation available on Mathematica on Export .json here what I did:

```
Export["distribution.json", 
  {"MixtureDistribution" -> {"Weight"-> {0.8744, 0.1255}},
   "LogisticDistribution"-> {"Parameter"-> 19.2103,0.1551}},
    "CauchyDistribution" -> {"Parameter"-> {23.5492, 2.2406}}
  }
]
```

It created .json file, but what i need is not to write manually the distribution and parameters, instead i would like to have these parameters and distribution to be automatically found in .json file.

I hope I am clear. Will be looking forward for the answers.

Comment: Start by reading through this: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html  You'll need to define a separate function to handle each type of distribution and convert them to the rule form you showed.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on defining a seperate funcion for each type of distribution? Will be looking for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
fun[MixtureDistribution[w_, dists_]] :=
  Prepend[
    Cases[dists, d_[p___] :> ToString[d] -> {"Parameter" -> {p}}], 
    "MixtureDistribution" -> {"Weight" -> w}
  ]

md = MixtureDistribution[
      {0.874492,0.125508},
      {LogisticDistribution[19.2103, 0.155169],
       CauchyDistribution[23.5492, 2.24062]}
     ]

fun[md] --> 
        {"MixtureDistribution" -> {"Weight" -> {0.874492, 0.125508}}, 
         "LogisticDistribution" -> {"Parameter" -> {19.2103, 0.155169}}, 
         "CauchyDistribution" -> {"Parameter" -> {23.5492, 2.24062}}}
```

You can then export this result.